# are syrup more flavorful than powder or similar?

Tags: flavor, vanilla, extracts, powder

I'm going to make a recipe which includes 
45 Grams of vanilla powder
2 Syrup pumps of Fruit syrup (20 Grams)

but i'm changing some in the recipe so i will use vanilla extract instead of powder and after doing the math 1 syrup pump = 10-10.25 grams,
so my question is , are extracts more flavorful than powder or similar ? 
so should i add 4.5 pumps of vanilla extract to the recipe or should i go lower.

Comment: You need to be very careful with the definition of "vanilla powder". It could be dried extract, it could be a powdered product flavoured with vanilla (real or artificial), or it could even be pure vanillin.  A link would be good, or a verbatim quote.

Comment: Extracts and syrup are different things, can you clarify in your question what products you mean?

Comment: @Tinuviel , Done, it's a syrup

Comment: @ChrisH , actually i was at a store and i asked for a recipe for the mango tango smoothie they make and the recipe is: 
45 gm of vanilla powder (pointing to the box the keep the powder in)
2 pumps of mango (Pointing to a big jar of a mango syrup) 
and spoon of cinnamon 

I hope that clarifies it enough

Comment: @user1294027 ok, but in the question you still talk about extract. I think it would be a good idea if you could link the exact product you are considering

Comment: @Tinuviel there is no link, it was a verbal recipe from a barista i know.

Comment: @ChrisH all belnded in a 16 ounce cup of ice

Comment: Hm if we don't know what their vanilla powder actually is this will be very difficult to answer. Also, to convert directly from dry weight of a vanilla powder to the weight of a liquid is difficult because it depends on whether the liquid is water or alcohol and on the concentration of the flavoring agent. I would suggest you make the smoothie with different amounts of extract/syrup and adjust until you find the ratio whose taste you like best.

Comment: @Tinuviel , i was considering the same, i will try to sample the recipe all in grams to find the desired the result. 
Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

> 45 gm of vanilla powder (pointing to the box the keep the powder in) 2 pumps of mango (Pointing to a big jar of a mango syrup) and spoon of cinnamon
>
> all belnded in a 16 ounce cup of ice

That sounds like it's vanilla-flavoured powder of some sort, perhaps milk-based, (or plant-milk-based), perhaps including maltodextrin, to give texture as well,  It could even be flavoured protein powder in some places (though they'd normally say so); that's about the right quantity compared to when I've made chocolate-vanilla milkshake with vanilla protein powder.

Certainly anything purer than that wouldn't be used in such large quantities.

As far as mimicking it goes, I'd start by using a teaspoonful of extract, and 45g of your best guess as to the rest of the powder.